# How do I combine same named values in a checkbox and give them a default value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my Code

```
<form method="get" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="all">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="cat">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="dog">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="bird">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="horse">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

when I submit the URL looks like

> http://localhost/project/search.php?animal[]=cat&animal[]=bird

but I want that the URL looks like this

> http://localhost/project/search.php?animal=cat+bird

And when I don't select a checkbox then should "all" be the default one like

> http://localhost/project/search.php?animal=all

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is the expected behavior of an HTML Form. If you want it to pass another value, you may need to make use of JavaScript or jQuery to format your HTTP request the way you want instead of the way HTML does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, when you have a form like:

```
<form method="get" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="all">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="cat">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="dog">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="bird">
  <input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="horse">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The browser creates a HTTP GET request with like the following:

`http://localhost/project/search.php?animal[]=cat&animal[]=bird`

this is basically sending an array of data:

```
animal = [
  "cat",
  "bird"
];
```

PHP can then accept this, and will see:

```
$_GET['animal'] array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "cat" [1]=> string(4) "bird" }
```

This is the expected behavior.

If you want to pass a String of data, example given: `cat+bird` or `all`, the you will need to construct the string data first. Since the browser does not know how to do this, we will need to use JavaScript to do so. I prefer jQuery, a framework for JavaScript. This might look like:

```
$(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var myData = [];
    var dataString = "animal=";
    $("form input[type='checkbox']").each(function(index, element){
      if($(element).is(":checked")){
        myData.push($(element).val());
      }
    });
    if(myData.length){
      dataString += myData.join("+");
    } else {
      dataString += "all";
    }
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/project/search.php?" + dataString;
  });
});
```

Now, PHP will get something like:

```
$_GET['animal'] string(8) "cat+bird"
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**

Assuming you have a form like this:

```
<form method="get" action="">
  <fieldset class="animal">
    <input type="checkbox" value="cat">
    <input type="checkbox" value="dog">
    <input type="checkbox" value="bird">
    <input type="checkbox" value="horse">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="country">
    <input type="checkbox" value="japan">
    <input type="checkbox" value="australia">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

You could build a data string by iterating over each set of checkboxes.

```
$(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var myData = {};
    var dataString = "";
    $("form fieldset").each(function(i1, el1){
      var class = $(el1).attr("class");
      myData[class] = [];
      $(el1).find("[type='checkbox']").each(function(i2, el2){
        if($(el2).is(":checked")){
          myData[class].push($(el2).val());
        }
      });
    });
    if(myData.length){
      $.each(myData, function(k, v){
        dataString += k + "=" + v.join("+") + "&";
      });
      dataString.slice(0,-1);
    } else {
      dataString += "all";
    }
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/project/search.php?" + dataString;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it works how I want except for one thing and that the content is given 5 times like  search.php?animal=allall+catall+catall+catall+cat  and is there a way to use a second filter or a search include this funktion like search.php?k="searchkeyword"&animal=bird+cat&country=japan+austria

Comment: @Nico261 Updated and fixed. The `$.each` loop should not have included the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you so much for this it works perfectly. But is there a way to include a second name like search.php?animal=cat&county=japan+austria  ? @Twisty

Comment: @Nico261 Yes there is.

Comment: Thank you for this. I know I've already asked you enough but is it also possible to include a  text field <input type="text" name="k"> where I can write always something else in it and that will also include in the URL like search.php?k=alwaysrandom&animal=cat+dog&country=japan+austria  @Twisty

Comment: @Nico261 yes there is.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @Twisty

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JavaScript you could do something easy like that:
I've used an `hidden` `input` that is filled according to which `checkbox`es are checked.
(See comments in my snippet for details)

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox][name=animals]'); // Get all checkboxes
var animals = document.querySelector('input[type=text][name=animal]');     // Get the hidden input
var country = document.querySelector('input[type=text][name=country]');    // Get the country input

// function that updates the hidden input
function update_animals() {
  var temp = [];                           // Temporary empty array
  for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {   // For all cbs
    if (cbs[i].checked) {                  // If the checkbox is checked…
      temp.push(cbs[i].value);             // … append value to the array.
    }
  }
  animals.value = temp.join('+') || 'all'; // Join all the values with '+', or put 'all' if no values
}
update_animals(); // Launch the function on load

// Bind the above function on all checkboxes, when (un)checking them
for (var i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
  cbs[i].onchange = update_animals;
}

// On form submission, do the following:
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = function(){
  var host = "http://localhost/project/search.php";
  var query = "?animal=" + animals.value + "&country=" + country.value;
  var url = host + query;
  console.log(url); // Here is the url where we will go if you uncomment below
  // window.location.href = url;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="">
  <p>Animals:
    <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="cat">
    <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="dog">
    <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="bird">
    <input type="checkbox" name="animals" value="horse">
    <input type="text" name="animal" hidden>
  </p>
  <p><input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country…"></p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">  ←  Click to see the url where we should go
</form>
```

Note that I used vanilla Jasacript.
You should be able to implement it easily without changing too much of your code.
There is no need to use a library or to complicate things.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Might consider hiding the text field and using an alternate names for checkboxes. In this way `animal` will be populated with the text and the checkboxes can be ignored.

Comment: @Twisty I've just made some modifications. :)

Comment: Nice alternative!

Comment: Yeah I also tried this code but I only see the result in the console so how do I move it into the URL

Comment: @Nico261Nico I've added the `form` `onsubmit`.